# dicomrt2matlab - how to load data after conversion

Tags: matlab, dicom

I am using the program dicomrt2matlab. I was able to convert the dicom RT structure into matlab and I got the .mat file as well. How do I load the .mat file into matlab next? How can I see the RT information in my applied to my dicom files ?

Link - https://github.com/ulrikls/dicomrt2matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do `data=load('myfilename.mat');` data will contain everything on it.

It shoudl have (I think) the following 3 data on it: `'contours', 'rtssheader', 'imageheaders'`

you can access it as `data.imageheaders`

Comment: can I apply it actually on the dicom images as such to see segmented images?

Comment: @AshwinVenkataraman if you are asking me about that tooolbox funcionality: no idea. you should ask the author, not me

Comment: Thanks for the help again !

Comment: @AshwinVenkataraman If it helped you, consider accepting the answer as valid ;)